# AWS staging to production

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-route53

We currently have our production elastic search on aws. Nightly we update the production elastic with new data (base data) and then we run scrips to merge new base with current production.

Know this works alright but production is off while this is happening. So i thought that i can do all on staging elastic search environment on aws and then when its done just somehow switch to production.

So here my flow.

- spin up new elastic search instance (staging)
- populate data (staging)
- run scripts (merging production to staging)
- switch somehow
- remove/delete/shutdown old production

I looked at aws route 53 and this looks promising. Basically fiddle with dns settings making "productionelastic" point to staging and then shutdown production instance.

Is there anything else i can do, also will route 53 idea work.

Comment: Route53 should work. You may run into a huddle if you are doing ssl. The SSL cert behind the elastisearch domain will not map to your DNS and you may need to add an exception.

Comment: Luckily not our elastic is not visibile from the outside so no need for ssl. thanks

Comment: So ur running ur custom elastisearch, I thought u were using aws elastisearch. The SSL issue does not really apply to ur setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Amazon Route 53 Health Checks and DNS Failover](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) to route requests to the healthy Elastisearch service while the other one is undergoing maintenance, using health checks, and DNS failover:

> If you have multiple resources that perform the same function, for
>   example, web servers or email servers, and you want Amazon Route 53 to
>   route traffic only to the resources that are healthy, you can
>   configure DNS failover by associating health checks with your resource
>   record sets. If a health check determines that the underlying resource
>   is unhealthy, Amazon Route 53 routes traffic away from the associated
>   resource record set. For more information, see Configuring DNS
>   Failover.

Using this service you can switch between both instances according to their availability. See [Configuring DNS Failover](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-configuring.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used a iis reverse proxy rule.

- create es instance
- wait for it to be ready and created
- run a powershell to update a fake website rewrite rule to point to
  new instance

and then i use the fake website in the production code.

I will use the route53 when  i have someone to manage it for me.

thanks